# Cannot find or login to Oracle Cloud DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

**Setup:** Oracle Cloud Infrastructure
Oracle Cloud DB: Autonomous DB.  DB#1( Data Warehouse), DB#2(Transaction Processing)

**Problem:** I can access DBs from Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Website, and using SQL Developer from my local computer, but I am not able to access them from SSH instance from my local computer.

I ssh to the instance with abc ID, next I look for Oracle DBs that I created; I cannot find them. I don't have abc id listed in those 2 DBs.

What do I need to do to access my DBs from SSH ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you are trying to connect to the DB from your instance. In that case, I would recommend you to configure a service gateway in that particular VCN (where the instance belongs) to connect to your DB service. Even after that make sure you have the proper rules in the route table and the security list.

Please refer the document on [connecting to ADB](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Database/Tasks/adbconnecting.htm#about), this might be useful.

Comment: Anupam, Thanks for your reply and help. I don't understand VCN & Oracle never makes it easy for every one to understand Oracle documentation.  They normally provide half or incomplete instructions.  I currently have 2 VCNs. The original VCN that was created initially by Oracle has 1 subnet, I think that my DBs are associated with that subnet, but I don't know how check that.   The second VCN, that I created after reading your reply has Private and Public Subnets.  I can go to route tables, but I don't know what I need to add there. Still not sure how to access my DBs from SSH.  Thanks.

Comment: is it like you are trying to access your autonomous DB from instance using ssh or is it a VM DB?

Comment: I found a great article on "Use SSH Tunnel to connect to Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse". I would request you to have a look on this. The article looks very descriptive and might be helpful. [link] https://qiita.com/RexZheng/items/c485bec6fc73f3dfd28a

Comment: Hi Anupum, I login to my instance using SSH, next I look for my DBs, which I cannot find or login to.  It is not a VM DB.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Aim, autonomous DB is like a serverless. Once you provision any ATP/ADW you donot get any IP for that DB so that you can ssh to that and connect. It is possible only for baremetal and VM DB. For ATP/ADW you need to connect using Oracle offered service console options or sql developer.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, and I couldn't find anywhere.   Thank you Anupam for your help and patience.  I really appreciate it.